# UIBarButtonItem changes font after being pressed, specified in appearance proxy

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, ios7

I set up `UIBarButtonItem` title font through `appearance` proxy in AppDelegate:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Segoe Print" size: 14.0], UITextAttributeFont,
                                                      DEF_TITLE_COLOR,UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                      [UIColor colorWithRed:100/255 green:128/255 blue:43/255 alpha:0.4], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil]
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal&UIControlStateHighlighted&UIControlStateDisabled];
```

And after that I am calling `presentViewController::` in some place of my app. Bar button is shown with proper font and background image, which I set up in this ViewController (not through appearance):

[image]

But when I press "Join" button, standard non-customized UIAlertView is shown, and right after it appears on the screen my barButton font changes to ... standard? And color also looks like tint color. I have no Idea what I am doing wrong, tried loads of things to figure it out:

[image]

This bug appears only on iOS7.

Comment: @user2277872 This doesn't help. Having same issue. When I am trying to separate states with '|', as null suggested, proxy not working at all, even not changing font for Normal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've figured that apperance proxy doesn't work as I expected. I copy-pasted customization method right before a place where `UIBarButtonItem` is initialized, and it worked as charm.

Comment: The same - helped. I have had connected that UIBarButtonItem with storyboard. So I tried to reinit the button with [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init] and manually set attributed to it (rather than using those in storyboard). Worked, but weird, I think it's Apple bug.

Comment: There is a radar for that https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/15652

Answer (score -1):

This may work in case of iOS 7 :

In `viewDidLoad` method:

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`

and set Font properties as well.

Comment: This property changes only color of "<" sign on backButtons. I am already using it in app initialization.