# iOS 7 UIBarButtonItem font changes when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uibarbuttonitem

I'm attempting to change my `UIBarButtonItem` font. It looks good when ViewControllers load. But if I tap on the bar button, or swipe right as if to move to the previous ViewController (but then pull back to the current one), the font changes back to the system font. Here's what I'm setting in my AppDelegate:

```
NSDictionary* barButtonItemAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Light" size:20.0f]};
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: barButtonItemAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: barButtonItemAttributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: barButtonItemAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: barButtonItemAttributes forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

And here's an example of my viewWillAppear:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141.0/255.0 green:209.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Am I somehow changing the font back, or am I misusing the appearance proxy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the `tintColor` setting conflicts with the title text attributes. Comment out that line and all will be well.

If you are going to use title text attributes, then incorporate the text color into those attributes:

```
NSDictionary* barButtonItemAttributes =
@{NSFontAttributeName:
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:20.0f],
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName:
      [UIColor colorWithRed:141.0/255.0 green:209.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]  
 };
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be true. But how can I change the button color on a per-ViewController basis?

Comment: In iOS 7, NSAttributedString is a first-class object, and color is therefore now a text attribute. So instead of using the appearance proxy and having it conflict with an individual `tintColor`, just make the button and give its text the attributes you want, including both font and color.

Comment: Now, having said all that, the truth is that you have walked into a massive iOS 7 bug here. A little search on stack overflow will reveal _many_ people suffering similar problems, such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935574/uibarbuttonitem-changes-font-after-being-pressed-specified-in-appearance-proxy?rq=1 Basically, you should try to narrow down the bug to a simply demonstrable case and then report it to Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm wondering if I can query the appearance proxy when this manually in the ViewController? So, when I "overwrite" the titleTextAttributes, I can use what's already stored there from AppDelegate?

Comment: If the problem is that you don't want to set the text attributes explicitly for each bar button item but that different bar button items have different colors, why not use the "contained in" version of the appearance proxy to set things differently for different view controllers up front?

Comment: @Matt: thank you for the suggestion!..I was searching SO for a while looking to achieve this, but only your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 3):

By using this approach in viewDidLoad method you can set custom text,font,size etc all at once place.

```
UIView *customBarButtonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];

UIButton *buttonDone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[buttonDone addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

buttonDone.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 50, 30);

buttonDone.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141.0/255.0 green:209.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
buttonDone.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Light" size:20.0f];
[buttonDone setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customBarButtonView addSubview:buttonDone];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:customBarButtonView];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
_myrButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"French KeyBoard" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(RbuttonItemdown:)];

NSDictionary* itemTextAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:12.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor lightGrayColor]};

[_myrButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:itemTextAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:_myrButtonItem];
```

You can use all of this :

```
NSString *const  NSFontAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSForegroundColorAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSBackgroundColorAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSLigatureAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSKernAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSStrokeColorAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSStrokeWidthAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSShadowAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSTextEffectAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSAttachmentAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSLinkAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSUnderlineColorAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSObliquenessAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSExpansionAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSWritingDirectionAttributeName ;
NSString *const  NSVerticalGlyphFormAttributeName;
```