# UIBarButtonItem tint color not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios10, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

I have recently noticed that the behaviour of the `tintColor` property has changed significantly in one of the recent iOS 10 updates.

I had a code which was working perfectly previously and which now is not working at all.

In one of my apps I have a collection of `UIBarButtonItem`s which are added to the `toolbarItems` array of the view controller. They are displayed fine.

However, at some point I want to change the tint color of certain items in response to the user action. The code is trivial:

```
flagButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This code used to work before, but now it doesn't work! I have verified that a reference to the `UIBarButtonItem` exists and that this line of code is executed. However, the tint color is not changing as it should.

In the description of the `tintColor` property it says:

> To refresh subview rendering when this property changes, override the tintColorDidChange() method.

I tried adding the `tintColorDidChange` method but it is not called. My assumption at this stage is that once `tintColor` is changed my button is not refreshed automatically.

Could someone help with finding a way to refresh it manually? The button is a standard `UIBarButtonItem` with an image.

## Update 1

Actually I noticed that if I change the `tintColor` of the toolbar instead of an individual item the code is working. It seems that for some reason setting the tint color on individual items no longer works. Does anyone know why this is the case?

## Update 2

Thanks to matt's hint I was able to find the source of the problem. It was caused by the code executed when the app was launched:

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setTintColor:[ColourTheme sharedTheme].navBackground];
```

Now, I am completely puzzled as to why this line caused problems with the `UIBarButtonItem` tint color... It might be because it introduced some ambiguities into the `UIAppearance`. Anyway, as I no longer need this line myself I can remove it easily. I will still leave my question open as I think that such behaviour is super weird and so, in a way, the question is still unanswered.

Just as an additional info - the view controller which experienced these problems contained a table view in it.

Comment: Wau I have exactly same problem

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce any problem. Here you can see we are alternating the tint color of the right bar button item between red and green; this is done by setting the bar button item's `tintColor` directly in code:

[image]

```
        let c = self.replyButton.tintColor
        if c == UIColor.red {
            self.replyButton.tintColor = .green
        } else {
            self.replyButton.tintColor = .red
        }
```

Therefore I conclude that the issue you are seeing is caused by something else you haven't told us about.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Now that I know that this is not a new behaviour I started digging deeper and figured out that the problem exists because I am setting certain visual styling though the UIAppearance. I haven't yet figured out which of them causes the problem, but once I do I will update the question. In any case I think that it is a strange behaviour as setting tintColor manually should be able to overwrite any UIAppearance settings...

Comment: I have found the problem and I have updated my question. I am still 100% puzzled as to what the hell was going on, but thank you very much anyway for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You might also find this answer of mine relevant somehow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21592073/341994

Comment: thanks! However, I still do not understand how an appearance attribute for table cell can conflict with bar button item! :)

Comment: I don't understand that either. You might file a bug report with Apple if you can make a simple reproducible case.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem es him now I am trying to comment all appearance tintColor modifications what broke this here.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and ended up solving it by taking the following steps:

1) Create an outlet to the bar button item. Mine was called "closeButton"
2) Write the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  let barButtonAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
  closeButton.setTitleTextAttributes(barButtonAttributes, for: .normal)
}
```

Be sure to place the code in viewWillAppear as this overrides UIAppearance's default settings.

Answer (score 1):

So in my case, this line

`UIActivityIndicatorView.appearance.tintColor = FlatWhite;`

set in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions changed all UIBarItemItems.tintColor to default blue and it was not possible to change it other way than by setting tint color on parent bar...

When I comment this line everything work when uncomment it stops working. For me this is clear bug in IOS framework. That is hard to predict because it's little different in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal and it causes a problem.

```
public enum UIImageRenderingMode : Int {

     case automatic // Use the default rendering mode for the context where the image is used
     case alwaysOriginal // Always draw the original image, without treating it as a template
     case alwaysTemplate // Always draw the image as a template image, ignoring its color information

}
```

**Use .alwaysTemplate instead**

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller - In the Navigation Controller check the Navigation Bar View / Tint properties. I found this overrides any code put into ViewDidLoad for the View Controller.